# Laravel, JSON response

Tags: json, laravel-4

How can I get this to work and look right.

[image: Select Menu]

```
<?php $arr = (array) json_decode($item->options, true); ?>
<label>Please choose a variant</label><br />
<select name="options">

    <option>{{ implode(' ', $arr) }}</option>

</select>
```

But it's showing in one option instead of 3 in this case example.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without seeing your json, but you need to loop through the array of options:

```
<select name="options">
    <?php foreach($arr as $a):?>
        <option>{{{a}}}</option>
    <?php endforeach;?>

</select>
```